# Is P(Exactly one event occurring) the same thing as P(Either A or B, not both)?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Just curious, got kind of confused while studying!

Comment: If $A,B$ are the only events in consideration or in your sample space, then the two are indeed the same. Or at least that is how I would read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  "Exactly one of the two occurs" means "One of the two, but not both, occurs".

They are the same events, so they have the same probability measure.